# git commit from php won't work

Tags: php, git

I have a simple php script that execute a git commit action on a local git repo. It used to work great but since i moved to new server it stopped working. The exec response code is 128 and the output is blank.

My first thought was directory permissions or ownership, but I've tried everything and it doesn't help. Anyone have any idea what could be the problem or a way to identify the error better ?

This is a test code that reproduce the problem:

```
$repoName = 'test';

$dirpath = __DIR__;

if (! file_exists($dirpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $repoName)) {
    mkdir($dirpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $repoName, 0777, true);
}

exec('git init ' . $repoName);

$dirpath .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $repoName;
chdir($dirpath);

file_put_contents($dirpath. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '.gitkeep', '');
file_put_contents($dirpath. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'realFile.txt', 'this is a test');

exec('git add -A');

exec('git commit -a --author="user <user>" -m "test message"', $output, $returnCode);
echo "return code $returnCode<br/>";
echo "output:<br/>";
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: What does the `var_dump($output);` return? If nothing, add `2>&1`˙to the end of the shell command, and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `2>&1` at the end of the shell command, to redirect stderr to stdout.